# How to make Laravel eloquent request with 1 filter on many fields

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

In my Laravel 5.7/ mysql app I make request on a form with 10 filter inputs,
one of them ($filter_search) if non empty must be compared with all fields(string, number,
date, ref to fields of other tables) in resulting listing.

I made scope on this table fields:

```
    public function scopeGetBySearch($query, $search = null)
    {
        if (empty($search)) {
            return $query;
        }
        $tb= with(new StorageSpace)->getTable();
        return $query->where(
            $tb.'.number',  $search
        ) ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($search, $tb) {
            $query->where( $tb.".notes",  'like',  '%'.$search.'%' )
                ->orWhere($tb.".selling_range", $search)
                    ->orWhere($tb.".actual_storage_rent", $search)
                        ->orWhere($tb.".insurance_vat", $search)
//                            ->havingRaw("job_ref_no", $search)

        })
```

But I have a problem how can I set filter on job_ref_no field from other table :

```
 $storageSpacesCollection = StorageSpace
        ::getByStatus($filter_status)
        ->getById($relatedStorageSpacesArray)
        ->getByLocationId($filter_location_id, 'warehouses')
        ->getByCapacityCategoryId($filter_capacity_category_id, 'storage_capacities')
        ->getByLevel($filter_level)
        ->getByNumber($filter_number, true)
        ->orderBy('storage_spaces.id', 'asc')
        ->getByStorageCapacityId($filter_storage_capacity_id)
        ->getByClientId($filter_client_id)
        ->getByColorId($filter_color_id)
        ->getBySearch($filter_search)
```

//            ->havingRaw("job_ref_no = " . $filter_search)

```
        ->leftJoin( 'storage_capacities', 'storage_capacities.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.storage_capacity_id' )
        ->leftJoin( 'warehouses', 'warehouses.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.warehouse_id' )
        ->leftJoin( 'clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.client_id')
        ->select(
            "storage_spaces.*",

            \DB::raw( "CONCAT(storage_capacities.count, ' ', storage_capacities.sqft ) as storage_capacity_name" ),

            \DB::raw("( SELECT check_ins.job_ref_no FROM check_ins WHERE // I got job_ref_no field in subquesry  check_ins.storage_space_id=storage_spaces.id ORDER BY check_ins.id ASC limit 1 ) AS job_ref_no"),

            "warehouses.name as warehouse_name",
            "clients.full_name as client_full_name")
        ->get();
```

havingRaw does not work both in the scope and in the request above if to uncomment it.

2. I tried to use addSelect, like:

But with request :

```
        $storageSpacesCollection = StorageSpace
            ::getByStatus($filter_status)
            ->whereRaw('storage_spaces.id <= 8') // DEBUGGING
            ->getById($relatedStorageSpacesArray)
            ->getByLocationId($filter_location_id, 'warehouses')
            ->getByCapacityCategoryId($filter_capacity_category_id, 'storage_capacities')
            ->getByLevel($filter_level)
            ->getByNumber($filter_number, true)
            ->orderBy('storage_spaces.id', 'asc')
            ->getByStorageCapacityId($filter_storage_capacity_id)
            ->getByClientId($filter_client_id)
            ->getByColorId($filter_color_id)
            ->getBySearch($filter_search)

//            ->havingRaw("job_ref_no = " . $filter_search)

            ->leftJoin( 'storage_capacities', 'storage_capacities.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.storage_capacity_id' )
            ->leftJoin( 'warehouses', 'warehouses.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.warehouse_id' )
            ->leftJoin( 'clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.client_id')
            ->select(
                "storage_spaces.*",
                \DB::raw( "CONCAT(storage_capacities.count, ' ', storage_capacities.sqft ) as storage_capacity_name" ),
                "warehouses.name as warehouse_name",
                "clients.full_name as client_full_name")
            ->addSelect([
                'job_ref_no' => CheckIn::selectRaw('job_ref_no')->whereColumn('check_ins.storage_space_id', 'storage_spaces.id'),
            ])
            ->get();
```

But I got an error:

```
 local.ERROR: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given {"userId":11,"email":"nilovsergey@yahoo.com","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/the-box-booking/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php:1031)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'stripos() expec...', '/mnt/_work_sdb8...', 1031, Array)
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/the-box-booking/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php(1031): stripos(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder), ' as ')
#2 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Grammars\\Grammar->wrap(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder))
```

Which way is valid ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**

I try to create sql I need manually.

With Laravel request :

```
$storageSpacesCollection = StorageSpace
    ::getByStatus($filter_status)
    ->whereRaw('storage_spaces.id <= 8') // DEBUGGING
    ->getById($relatedStorageSpacesArray)
    ->getByLocationId($filter_location_id, 'warehouses')
    ->getByCapacityCategoryId($filter_capacity_category_id, 'storage_capacities')
    ->getByLevel($filter_level)
    ->getByNumber($filter_number, true)
    ->orderBy('storage_spaces.id', 'asc')
    ->getByStorageCapacityId($filter_storage_capacity_id)
    ->getByClientId($filter_client_id)
    ->getByColorId($filter_color_id)
    ->getBySearch($filter_search)

    ->leftJoin( 'storage_capacities', 'storage_capacities.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.storage_capacity_id' )
    ->leftJoin( 'warehouses', 'warehouses.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.warehouse_id' )
    ->leftJoin( 'clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.client_id')
    ->select(
        "storage_spaces.*",

        \DB::raw( "CONCAT(storage_capacities.count, ' ', storage_capacities.sqft ) as storage_capacity_name" ),

        \DB::raw("( SELECT check_ins.job_ref_no FROM check_ins WHERE check_ins.storage_space_id=storage_spaces.id ORDER BY check_ins.id ASC limit 1 ) AS job_ref_no"),

        "warehouses.name as warehouse_name",
        "clients.full_name as client_full_name")
    ->get();
```

And tracing I see sql statement with job_ref_no column :

```
   SELECT `storage_spaces`.*, CONCAT(storage_capacities.count, ' ', storage_capacities.sqft )     AS storage_capacity_name, (   SELECT check_ins.job_ref_no 
    FROM check_ins 
    WHERE check_ins.storage_space_id=storage_spaces.id 
    ORDER BY check_ins.id ASC limit 1 )     AS job_ref_no, `warehouses`.`name`     AS `warehouse_name`, `clients`.`full_name`     AS `client_full_name` 
    FROM `storage_spaces` 
    LEFT JOIN `storage_capacities` on `storage_capacities`.`id` = `storage_spaces`.`storage_capacity_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `warehouses` on `warehouses`.`id` = `storage_spaces`.`warehouse_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `clients` on `clients`.`id` = `storage_spaces`.`client_id` 
    WHERE storage_spaces.id <= 8     AND (`storage_spaces`.`number` = '999'     OR 
  
      (`storage_spaces`.`notes` like '%999%'     OR 
       `storage_spaces`.`selling_range` = '999'     OR 
       `storage_spaces`.`actual_storage_rent` = '999'     OR 
       `storage_spaces`.`insurance_vat` = '999') ) 
    ORDER BY `storage_spaces`.`id` asc
```

I want to set filter on job_ref_no column manually :

```
   SELECT `storage_spaces`.*, CONCAT(storage_capacities.count, ' ', storage_capacities.sqft )     AS storage_capacity_name, (   SELECT check_ins.job_ref_no 
    FROM check_ins 
    WHERE check_ins.storage_space_id=storage_spaces.id 
    ORDER BY check_ins.id ASC limit 1 )     AS job_ref_no, `warehouses`.`name`     AS `warehouse_name`, `clients`.`full_name`     AS `client_full_name` 
    FROM `storage_spaces` 
    LEFT JOIN `storage_capacities` on `storage_capacities`.`id` = `storage_spaces`.`storage_capacity_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `warehouses` on `warehouses`.`id` = `storage_spaces`.`warehouse_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `clients` on `clients`.`id` = `storage_spaces`.`client_id` 
    WHERE storage_spaces.id <= 8     AND (`storage_spaces`.`number` = '999'     OR 
  
      (`storage_spaces`.`notes` like '%999%'     OR 
       `storage_spaces`.`selling_range` = '999'     OR 
       `storage_spaces`.`actual_storage_rent` = '999'     OR 
       `storage_spaces`.`insurance_vat` = '999' OR 
       job_ref_no = '999' )   // I added this line @
     ) 
    ORDER BY `storage_spaces`.`id` asc
```

But I got error :

```
Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'job_ref_no' in 'where clause'
```

Which is valid way in raw sql and how it can be implemented with eloquent ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:**
I try to make with join:

```
        $storageSpacesCollection = StorageSpace
            ::getByStatus($filter_status)
            ->getById($relatedStorageSpacesArray)
            ->getByLocationId($filter_location_id, 'warehouses')
            ->getByCapacityCategoryId($filter_capacity_category_id, 'storage_capacities')
            ->getByLevel($filter_level)
            ->getByNumber($filter_number, true)
            ->orderBy('storage_spaces.id', 'asc')
            ->getByStorageCapacityId($filter_storage_capacity_id)
            ->getByClientId($filter_client_id)
            ->getByColorId($filter_color_id)
            ->getBySearch($filter_search)

            ->leftJoin( 'storage_capacities', 'storage_capacities.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.storage_capacity_id' )
            ->leftJoin( 'warehouses', 'warehouses.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.warehouse_id' )
            ->leftJoin( 'clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'storage_spaces.client_id')
            ->leftJoin( 'check_ins', 'check_ins.storage_space_id', '=', 'storage_spaces.id') // I ADDED THIS LINE
            ->select(
                "storage_spaces.*",

                \DB::raw( "CONCAT(storage_capacities.count, ' ', storage_capacities.sqft ) as storage_capacity_name" ),

//                \DB::raw("( SELECT check_ins.job_ref_no FROM check_ins WHERE check_ins.storage_space_id=storage_spaces.id ORDER BY check_ins.id ASC limit 1 ) AS job_ref_no"),

                "warehouses.name as warehouse_name",
                "check_ins.job_ref_no as job_ref_no",
                "clients.full_name as client_full_name")
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

and I have a sql :

```
   SELECT distinct `storage_spaces`.*, CONCAT(storage_capacities.count, ' ', storage_capacities.sqft )     AS storage_capacity_name, 
     `warehouses`.`name`     AS `warehouse_name`, `check_ins`.`job_ref_no`     AS `job_ref_no`, `clients`.`full_name`     AS `client_full_name` 
    FROM `storage_spaces` 
    LEFT JOIN `storage_capacities` on `storage_capacities`.`id` = `storage_spaces`.`storage_capacity_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `warehouses` on `warehouses`.`id` = `storage_spaces`.`warehouse_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `clients` on `clients`.`id` = `storage_spaces`.`client_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `check_ins` on `check_ins`.`storage_space_id` = `storage_spaces`.`id` 

    WHERE ( `storage_spaces`.`number` = 'S1-102'     OR (`storage_spaces`.`notes` like '%S1-102%'     OR `storage_spaces`.`selling_range` = 'S1-102'     OR 
`storage_spaces`.`actual_storage_rent` = 'S1-102'     OR `storage_spaces`.`insurance_vat` = 'S1-102'     OR `job_ref_no` = 'S1-102') ) 

    ORDER BY `storage_spaces`.`id` asc
```

I have have different results

1. I need to get only last row from check_ins, that is why in my request I have limit 1:

   ```
        \DB::raw("( SELECT check_ins.job_ref_no FROM check_ins WHERE check_ins.storage_space_id=storage_spaces.id ORDER BY check_ins.id ASC limit 1 ) AS job_ref_no"),
   ```

that is why have have several rows of as storage_spaces as all check_ins ae joined
2) I have all rows from storage_spaces and I do not see why

3. I tried to change leftJoin with Join /rightJoin but it did not help...

Thanks!

Comment: Pls, take a look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decision addin in scope :

```
->orWhereRaw("(SELECT check_ins.job_ref_no FROM check_ins WHERE
   check_ins.storage_space_id=storage_spaces.id ORDER BY check_ins.id ASC LIMIT 1) = '".$search."'")
```

and that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the join into the main query instead of select query because in select query it's not a actual column which you set into the where condition.

Comment: Could you, provide more details or give some example how to make it?

Comment: Use this ->join( 'check_ins', 'check_ins.storage_space_id', '=', 'storage_spaces.id ') instead of select clause

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Comment: You need to only use the join not a leftjoin because if leftjoin gives the result evenif search criteria not match into the check_ins table so if you do this then your column not found error resolved

Comment: I tried             ->join( 'check_ins', 'check_ins.storage_space_id', '=', 'storage_spaces.id')
but all the same all rows from storage_spaces ... Or do you mean different ?